# Как передать данные данные в дочернюю таблицу? Django

Tags: база-данных, django, model

Есть модель пользователя и в дочерней дополнительная информация о пользователе.

```
class main(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

class more(models.Model):
    a = date из модели main и прибавить к нему 4
    moree = models.CharField(max_length=50, value)
    moree = a
```

Берем значение `date`(оно вводиться в бд), на основе его генерируем новое значение и это значение заносим в дочернюю бд

Comment: Вам определенно нужно изучить работу классов в python. А модели соединяются через связи, это есть в документации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для чего нужна связанная таблица не понятно, когда можно добавить еще одно поле в текущую, но делается через связь один к одному. Пример

```
class Main(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    key = models.ForeignKey('More')


class More(models.Model):
    a = models.DateField()
    moree = models.CharField(max_length=50, value)
```

[Документация на русском языке](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/models/fields.html#foreignkey)

Вы описываете модель, поэтому +4 нужно делать при сохранении или обновлении данных.

В коде это выглядит примерно так:

```
# код не тестировался, возможно есть ошибки
from .models import Main
from .models import More

item = Main.object.get(id=1)
new_date = item.date + 4
Main.object.filter(id=1).update(key__date=newdate)
```

или обратный запрос

```
More.object.filter(main__id=1).update(date=new_date)
```

или третий вариант, когда узнаем id связанного элемента, по нему уже делаем обновление.

```
search_id = item.key__id
More.object.filter(id=search_id).update(date=new_date)
```

Comment: Д уже нашел про ForeignKey, но все равно спасибо (отметил как правильный ответ)

Comment: Спасибо. Опоздал немного с ответом, русскоязычным сообществом раньше не пользовался . К сожалению наше сообщество по django мало активное, хотя работать с django достаточно просто.